# Why does `take` with a large number return [] even though the list is infinite?

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation

I have a doubt on why Haskell couldn't handle the following line

```
Prelude> take 1000000000000 $ repeat ' '
```

That line of code will return:

```
""
```

Which is obviously not 1,000,000,000,000 spaces.

If I try one less zero, it will print a long time.

And the thing that bothers me the most is that if I just write

```
Prelude> repeat ' '
```

It will work, even being a *lot* of more zeros.

So, why couldn't Haskell just print for a long time like it did with the `repeat` alone?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Are you on a 32 bit system? I suspect 1000000000000 wraps `Int` into a negative number. It's equal to about `2^40`.

You can check what's going on by entering `1000000000000 :: Int`.

`take` with a negative number just returns the empty list:

```
Prelude> take (- 1) [1,2,3]
[]
```

For reference, `take` only takes `Int`:

```
Prelude> :t take
take :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
```

Comment: `take` takes `Int`. It's just a quirk of the Prelude.

Comment: `1000000000000 :: Int32` evaluates to `-727379968`, to be exact. Also, see: [`genericTake`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-List.html#v:genericTake).